# Leaving the Schengen E.U. with resident permit about to expire

Tags: schengen, transition-of-visa-status

I am trying to get a single answer to the question.

If I leave the eu on a resident permit from Poland that expires while I am out of the E.U. can I return to the E.U. at anytime following the expiration as a visitor on short term visit up to 90 days?   Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: As explained in the linked question, time spent in Schengen on a residence permit does not count toward the 90/180 day rule.

Comment: Im an American with American passport